# how to stay logged in after refreshing the page in React/Redux Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

i am securing routes using redux states. What i am doing is when user loggedIn i update redux state `isAuthenticated` in `signIn` component and receiving that state in my `AllRoutes` component and then i passed it in my custom route `ProtectedHomeRoute` as props. Everything is working fine but problem is when i refresh, i get `isAuthenticated` value `false` which is default value of it so because of this, `ProtectedHomeRoute` redirect me to `Login` page.

**Please suggest me the best way to handle browser refresh** on above mentioned use case.

i tried  to solve this in this way that i made a new action named `isLoggedIn` in this i am calling API to check login status, if response is then i am  passing true in payload

then i am calling this action in `componentDidMount` lifecyle of `AllRoutes`
so that when browser will refresh `isLoggedIn` will be called and ill get previous state but things is not happening is this way.

This is code of `isLoggedIn` action

```
export function isLoggedIn() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/checkLoginStatus").then(res => {
    let data = res.data; 
    let tid = data.data; // data contain userId
    console.log(tid);
    let isAuthenticate =  false
    if(tid){
      isAuthenticate = true;
    }  
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: "isLoggedIn",
        payload: isAuthenticate
      });
    };
  })
}
```

THis is auth Reducer code

```
    const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuthenticate: false
  };

  export default (states = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "loggedIn":
        return {
          ...states,
          isAuthenticate: action.payload
        };
      case "logOut":
        return {
          ...states,
          isAuthenticate: action.payload
        };
        case "isLoggedIn":
        return {
          ...states,
          isAuthenticate: action.payload
        };

      default:
        return states;
    }
  };
```

AllRouts component code

```
import { isLoggedIn } from "./store/action/authAction";
import axios from 'axios';

class AllRoutes extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    isLoggedIn();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticate);

    return (
      <Router>        
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth/signup" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/auth/signin" component={Signin} />
          <Route path="/auth/forgot" component={Forgot} />
          <Route exact path="/stock" component={Products} />
          <Route exact path="/stock/detail/:id" component={Manage} />
          <ProtectedHomeRoute
            exact
            path="/"
            component={<Home />}
            isAuthenticate={this.props.isAuthenticate}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

// to access redux stats as props in this component
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isAuthenticate: state.authReducer.isAuthenticate
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    userAuthenticate: a => {
      dispatch(isLoggedIn(a));
    }
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AllRoutes);

// protected route for Home component
const ProtectedHomeRoute = ({ component, isAuthenticate, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("protected route", isAuthenticate);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticate ? component : <Redirect to="/auth/signin" />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can we use cookie?

Comment: Are you working with tokens at all in your authentication logic?

Comment: @Isaac i know that i can save value in browser storage, but i don't want to do that . is there any other way ?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo yeah ,but i am getting a status and `data` which contains userId which is actually generated by firebase

Comment: If your idea is to using only `redux`, you can explore `redux-persist`: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist , but then again, underlying it uses cookies/ or storage to store your redux state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code i'm guessing that you are more of a front-end developer. you shouldn't use userId for authentication. you have to use something like jwt with expiration at your back-end. with jwt you can create a token for every logged in user. keep the token in LocalStorage and pass it as header with every request and make your private route require that token.
you can read jwt documentation and this should give you an idea of how it would look like:

Auth actions
[auth actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ypuq.png)

Auth reducer
[auth reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHlxC.png)

Private Route
[Private route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUUQC.png)